# Ignore file when calculating gradle cache fingerprint

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

In my project I access the `build-info.properties` generated by the gradle springboot plugin `buildInfo()` task during runtime to include my project version in log metadata.

My problem is that this file is included in the fingerprint calculation for gradle tasks such as tests via the classpath fingerprint, but the version in that file changes with every build in my pipelines. Therefore I can never reuse that cache.

I saw [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/exclude-file-from-classpath-runtime-does-not-have-desired-effect/35628) question on how to exclude that file from runtime, but if I follow that advise,

<s>the file's not available during runtime anymore, naturally.</s>

the file /BOOT-INF/classes/META-INF/build-info.properties is empty. Therefore my application fails on startup.

Can I somehow exclude it from the cache fingerprint calculation only?

Edits:

I'm currently on Gradle 6.8.1 and Spring Bot 2.2.2.

This is how I generate the file:

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

And this is how I add the normalization:

```
normalization {
    runtimeClasspath {
        ignore "**/build-info.properties"
    }
}
```

Update: As stated in the comment, this problem appeared due to a missconfiguration of my Gradle build scripts in another location. The `normalization` approach linked in the question and explained in the accepted answer is the solution to the initial question.

Comment: This isn't the answer, but similar issues have been raised with Gradle about other `.properties` files, such as here:  https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15820  Perhaps opening a ticket there may be an adequate solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gradle input normalization](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:configure_input_normalization) should be a solution for it.

```
normalization {
    runtimeClasspath {
        ignore '**/build-info.properties'
    }
}
```

Not sure why you are saying " if I follow that advise, the file's not available during runtime anymore". According to documentation

> The effect of this configuration would be that changes to build-info.properties would be ignored for up-to-date checks and build cache key calculations. Note that this will not change the runtime behavior of the test task — i.e. any test is still able to load build-info.properties and the runtime classpath is still the same as before.

Here are some tests that proves the above

**Running build first time**

```
./gradlew build  -Pversion=0.0.1 --console=plain
> Task :bootBuildInfo
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes
> Task :resolveMainClassName
> Task :bootJar
> Task :jar
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test
> Task :check
> Task :build
```

`test` task was executed because there is no build cache.

**Running build second time with different version**

```
./gradlew build  -Pversion=0.0.2 --console=plain
> Task :bootBuildInfo
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes
> Task :resolveMainClassName UP-TO-DATE
> Task :bootJar
> Task :jar
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test UP-TO-DATE
> Task :check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :build
```

As you may see only build tasks were executed but `test` task is still `UP-TO-DATE`.

`build-info.properties` is still available under `build/resources/main/META-INF/`

```
build.artifact=demo
build.group=com.example
build.name=demo
build.time=2023-02-01T18\:32\:03.871040Z
build.version=0.0.2
```

and could be accessed using Spring Boot actuator endpoint `/actuator/info` in case it's enabled

```
{
    "build": {
        "artifact": "demo",
        "name": "demo",
        "version": "0.0.2",
        "group": "com.example"
    }
}
```

**Consider excluding build time**
You could optimize even more by excluding time from the build info.

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo {
        excludes = ['time']
    }
}
```

Usually it's a good idea for optimizing local builds. Otherwise `build` tasks will be always executed. By excluding time all tasks will be cached

```
./gradlew build --console=plain
> Task :bootBuildInfo UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :resolveMainClassName UP-TO-DATE
> Task :bootJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :assemble UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test UP-TO-DATE
> Task :check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :build UP-TO-DATE
```

but `build.time` will not be part of the  `build-info.properties`

```
build.artifact=demo
build.group=com.example
build.name=demo
build.version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: After another test: When I build with the normalization, the file build-info.properties in /BOOT-INF/classes/META-INF/ still exists, but is empty. Therefore my application fails on startup (I reference the file content in my logback configuration).
If it's relevant, I'm currentlY using Gradle 6.8.1

Comment: Validated on Gradle `6.8.1` and Spring Boot `2.2.2.RELEASE` and everything works as expected. I would suggest to create minimal reproducible example and validate other gradle tasks.

Comment: Yeah I could also validate that on an empty project. As you said, something else in my setup must cause my problem.